# Soft keyboard not appearing on genymotion HTC

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, htcsense

I have downloaded the device on genymotion that is HTC One - 4.4.4 - API-19. The problem is that the soft keyboard is not appearing at all. I have tried with the ime coding as

```
edPost.requestFocus();
imm.showSoftInput(edPost, 0);
```

Then I thought may be I am mistaking somewhere in my code. I have checked the default message app of this device where I can't see the soft keyboard to type the message or destination number. Even anywhere the keyboard may appear I can't see it at all. Please help me with any kind of knowledge about this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Settings --> Language & Input --> Current Keyboard

Here in this dialog Turn On the "Hardware" Toggle button.

Answer (score 3):

checkmark **use virtual keyboard for text input** from genymotion device setting.

see attached image.

[image: setting]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Tejas, it is not the correct answer. I have unchecked the "use virtual keyboard for text input" as you have attached on image and still able to display the soft keyboard by this way. See the below image

[image]

Thanks.